# How to change the default port of Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs

How to change the default port 8080 of Team Foundation Server 2010? Not only the web access, and the Visual Studio teamwork manage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can change it in the installer or the TFS Admin Console.  However, you can change it manually in IIS just like you would change the port of any other IIS Web Site.

Answer (score 0):

you can change on iis website port and "change public URL" on TFS Administration Console Aplication Tier.